# Sphinx autosummary not showing attributes summary

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I used `Sphinx==1.6.3` to build my docs using `sphinx-build -a docs/source docs/build` and include `sphinx.ext.autosummary` in the extensions listed in conf.py. I want a summary of the method and attributes similar to [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame)

I have a number attributed defined using the @property decorator:

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._X = None

    @property
    def X(self):
        '''
        :Getter: Returns X
        '''
        return self._X
```

Sphinx will build the docs, build a Methods summary, will list the attributes with the other methods, but will not make a Attributes summary.

Do I need to explicitly instruct Sphinx to include attributes as part of the auto summary?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it sounds similar to this Sphinx issue, [Doc in decorated function not generated](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3783). If not, there are several other open issues containing ["decorator"](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=decorator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including attributes that are documented using the `@property` decorator similar to [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) you need to take advantage of the [numpydoc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpydoc) package and include `numpydoc` in the extensions list in `conf.py`